# get values selected in g:select tag

Tags: jquery, grails, select

In my grails project I have the following select:

```
<g:select name="receiptItems" multiple="multiple"/>
```

I want to get values currently selected when a checkbox is checked or unchecked.
I do the following:

```
 <g:checkBox name="hasStampDuty" value="${receiptInstance?.hasStampDuty}"
            onclick="${remoteFunction(
                    controller: 'Receipt',
                    action: 'addStampDuty',
                    params: '\'receiptItemsSelected=\' + document.getElementById(\'receiptItems\').value+\'&receiptInstance=' + receiptInstance+'&ischecked=\'+this.checked',
                    onSuccess: 'updateTotalAmount(\'totalAmount\', data, \'00000\')')}"
 />
```

but `document.getElementById(\'receiptItems\').value` returns only the first selected value of the g:select.

I've also tried with `$(\'receiptItems\')` or `$(\'"receiptItems"\')` or `jQuery(\'receiptItems\')` but they do not work as expected.

EDIT:
I've also tried with `jQuery(\'receiptItems\').val()` and it does not work

How can I solve this?

Comment: If you are using jQuery use .val()

Comment: done, but it does not work too

Comment: $("#hasStampDuty").val() doesn't give you a value?

Comment: is it needed to use the #?

Comment: That's how you reference an element by the HTML/dom id. So, in this case yes. I recommend you read up on jQuery selectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your selector is wrong, try this following (not i dont know how grails works):

```
$('select[name="receiptItems"]').val();
```

The first gives the type of element youre looking for and the second part is the unique name of that element. I personally am not a fan of using names and prefer ID's for important things; were you to change your first line to

```
<g:select id="receiptItems" multiple="multiple"/>
```

You can select and get its value using:

```
$('#receiptItems').val()
```

HTH